# Stored Procedure works in Mysql workbench but not in C# code

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a stored procedure which I want to delete and then want to re-create it. It is working from Mysql workbench but not working from c# code.

I am using MySql Workbench 6.3 CE

This is the dry run of the stored procedure:

```
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS AccountGetAccountOpeningClosingStock;
 DELIMITER $$
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE 
 `AccountGetAccountOpeningClosingStock`(IN _endDate datetime)
  BEGIN
  Select * From openingclosingstock Where CreateDate <= _endDate order by 
  CreateDate asc;
  END$$
  DELIMITER ;
```

This is the call from the C# code:

```
string myConnectionString = FetchDbConnectionString(environment, item);
MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);

MySqlCommand mySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(storedProcedureSqlQuery, mySqlConnection);

await mySqlConnection.OpenAsync();

var reader = await mySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync();

while (await reader.ReadAsync())
{
     // do something
}

reader.Close();
await mySqlConnection.CloseAsync();
```

Error from C# code :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$
>   CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `AccountGetAccountOpeningClosi' at line 1

I created an app for an example : 
[Demo stored procedure](https://github.com/spartha1995/DemoStoreProcedure,)

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `storeProcedureSqlQuery`?

Comment: I have attached a Demo project, please kindly check that you will get to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and it is working perfectly.

**C# Code:**

```
string myConnectionString = FetchDbConnectionString(environment, item);
MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);

const string sqlQuery ="DELIMITER $$ DELIMITER $$ DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS AccountGetAccountOpeningClosingStock; $$ CREATE PROCEDURE AccountGetAccountOpeningClosingStock(IN _endDate datetime) BEGIN Select * From tutorials_tbl Where CreateDate <= _endDate order by CreateDate asc; END$$ $$  DELIMITER; DELIMITER;";
MySqlScript script = new MySqlScript();
script.Connection = mySqlConnection;
script.Query = sqlQuery;
script.Execute();
mySqlConnection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to get the proc to recreate and run at the same time.
This should get you the data you are looking for else call the procedure in SQL to get the data. If you are trying to recreate(test if it is there) do it in a separate part of the program before you need the data.

```
string myConnectionString = FetchDbConnectionString(environment, item);
MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
string SQLC= "Select * From openingclosingstock Where CreateDate <= _endDate 
order by CreateDate asc;"
MySqlCommand mySqlCommand = new 
MySqlCommand(SQLC, mySqlConnection);
await mySqlConnection.OpenAsync();
var reader = await mySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync();
while (await reader.ReadAsync())
{
    //do something
}
reader.Close();
await mySqlConnection.CloseAsync();
```

OR are you creating the producer here to call it later?

Remove DELIMITER $$ at the beginning and $$ after the last END

DELIMITER is a MySQL client command that enables you to change its statement terminator temporarily while you define a stored routine.

If you are defining a stored routine from within a programming interface that does not use the semicolon as a statement terminator, semicolons within stored routine definitions do not present any special issues.

Don't know if that code will work. maybe try this:

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{ 
conn.Open();

    using (MySqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        using (MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = query;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

         trans.Commit();
    }
}
```

and SQL:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS AccountGetAccountOpeningClosingStock;
 CREATE PROCEDURE AccountGetAccountOpeningClosingStock(IN endDate datetime) 

 BEGIN 
 Select * From openingclosingstock
 Where CreateDate <= endDate order by CreateDate; 

 END;
```

Comment: I need to create the stored procedure.
As i mention that  **_I want to delete and then want to re-create it_**.

Comment: Edited Sql query:
**DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS AccountGetAccountOpeningClosingStock;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `AccountGetAccountOpeningClosingStock`(IN _endDate datetime)
BEGIN
Select * From openingclosingstock Where CreateDate <= _endDate order by CreateDate asc;**



Error Message :
**_You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3_**

Comment: remove DEFINER=root@% and see if it not that giving the issue

Comment: I checked every possible scenario but it is not working

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you declared storeProcedureSqlQuery

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172075/discussion-between-partha-and-jaco-van-deventer).