# Mysql Store Procedure query Execution From C#

Tags: c#, mysql

**Query from SQL workbench:**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS AccountGetAccountOpeningClosingStock;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE 
`AccountGetAccountOpeningClosingStock`(IN _endDate datetime)
BEGIN
Select * From openingclosingstock Where CreateDate <= _endDate order by 
CreateDate asc;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The above Procedure call is working perfectly from Mysql Workbench.
Now I want to execute this query through **C#**. First of all the above query wasn't executing due to Syntax error form C#.

I found some way to execute a query which will perform the same operation.

**SQL query:**

```
DELIMITER $$
DELIMITER $$ 
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS AccountGetAccountOpeningClosingStock; 
$$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE AccountGetAccountOpeningClosingStock(IN _endDate datetime) 
BEGIN Select * From tutorials_tbl Where CreateDate <= _endDate order by CreateDate asc; 
END$$ 
$$  
DELIMITER; 
DELIMITER;
```

Here you can see I added an extra `DELIMITER`.

**So my question is can I execute the same SQL query from C#. If its possible then how?**

Comment: try CommandType.StoredProcedure when you execute your command against MySQL server.

Comment: @Adrian it's not working.

Comment: what is the error code you seen when executing MySQL queries

Comment: Error code executing Mysql query :
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `AccountGetAccountOpeningClosi' at line 1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stored Procedure works in Mysql workbench but not in C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50603814/stored-procedure-works-in-mysql-workbench-but-not-in-c-sharp-code)